# jQuery multiple conditional statements

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have this code:

```
    $('#inputID').on('keyup', function () {
      if ($('#inputID').val() == '') {
          $(".button").removeClass('uk-button-success');
      } else {
          $(".button").addClass('uk-button-success');
      }
    })
```

It requires a single input to be filled, so a specific button gets a class added.
Now I want multiple inputs to be checked and if all of them are filled and not empty, I want to add the class "uk-button-success" to a button.

```
 if ($('#inputID', '#inputID2').val() == '')
```

and other stuff I've tried didn't work.

How do I do this?

Comment: You might try to use a logical `OR` operator: `if ($('#inputID').val() == '' || $('#inputID2').val() == '' || ...) { /* some of them is empty */} else {/* all are filled */}`

Comment: This works, nice! How do I get the multiple IDs now with the keyup function? $('#inputID1', '#inputID2').on('keyup', function () { doesn't work.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky there is a better way, see below ;)

Comment: @Jonas Set, for ex., the same class name for all inputs. Let it be `my-input`. And then you may use `$('.my-input').on('keyup', function () {...`?

Comment: @StéphaneM As fas as I understand, it allows to check clicked input value only (`$(this).val()`), but not other inputs (quote: `I want multiple inputs to be checked and if all of them are filled and not empty`).

Comment: @Jonas Have a look at this demo https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/qBRQqOP Hope it help you somehow.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky i add another exemple for this use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just target by class to have multiple element and then use $(this)

**Eg: On a batch of input to disable (or not) submiting following all values.**

```
$(function() {
  $('.input').on('keyup', function() {
    result = true
    $('.input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        result = false
      }
    })
    result ? $("#target").prop('disabled', false) : $("#target").prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g84p5b6v/

Your base use case

```
$(function() {
    $('.input').on('click', function () {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
          $("#target").removeClass('success');
      } else {
          $("#target").addClass('success');
      }
    })
});
```

=> https://jsfiddle.net/45of2nrk/